# standard browser EventDispatcher class to inherit from

Tags: javascript

I often implement my own EventDispatcher class in JS from scratch. I guess there is some implementation of it somewhere in browsers for DOM elements, but EventDispatchers are useful even for other things not related at all to the DOM. Is there any standard class in browsers that I can inherit from? I need something where I can call `addEventListener("event", listener)`, `removeEventListener("event", listener)` and `dispatchEvent("event")` and I need it to support multiple listeners for the same event. There is EventEmitter from node, but I'm not very familiar with it and I don't know if it'll work in the browser. Should I use it and maybe transpile the entire thing with something like browserify?

Comment: There's [EventTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget) which is the interface where you get the add/removeEventListener and dispatch methods from, is that what you are looking for?

Comment: EventTarget works. That's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already an interface defined that gives you all 3 methods, [EventTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget)

> [Spec](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-eventtarget)
>
> ```
> interface EventTarget {
>   void addEventListener(DOMString type, EventListener? callback, optional (AddEventListenerOptions or boolean) options);
>   void removeEventListener(DOMString type, EventListener? callback, optional (EventListenerOptions or boolean) options);
>   boolean dispatchEvent(Event event);
> };
> ```

So all you would need to do is inherit from that interface

```js
class MyObject extends EventTarget {
  myCallback(){
    console.log('event triggered');
  }
  myCallback2(){
    console.log('event2 triggered');
  }
}

var obj = new MyObject;
obj.addEventListener('test',obj.myCallback);
obj.addEventListener('test',obj.myCallback2);
obj.dispatchEvent(new Event('test'))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no "no DOM" class you could extend, but RxJS Subjects may fit your needs.

**RxJS**

You can

- subscribe as many listeners as you need
- call next() to "fire" an event

Example:

```
// Basic example
const emitter = new Subject();
emitter.subscribe(event => console.log(event));
emitter.next({ type: 'my-custom-event', … });


// class example
class MyClass {
  change = new Subject();
  myFn() {
    this.change.next();
  }
}

const bar = new MyClass();
bar.change.subscribe(e => console.log('change triggered'));

// test
bar.myFn();
=> logs 'change triggered'
```

You'll find a lot of documentation around angular/typescript but rxjs does not depend on angular.

See: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/

**EventTarget**

As long as your inside a browser, there's the EventTarget interface. In most browsers (as time of writing no Edge, no IE) it provides a conststructor and you can extend from it (ECMA 2015).

```
class MyClass extends EventTarget {
  myFn() {
    this.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
  }
}

const bar = new MyClass();
bar.addEventListener('change', e => console.log('change triggered'));

// just for testing
bar.myFn();
=> logs 'change triggered'
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget

Answer (score 0):

The event dispatching/listening is part of the DOM API, not Javascript itself. You cannot use this mechanism without DOM nodes. There are tons of good, simple libraries or more advanced ones, and it's quite trivial to implement yourself (cf the amount of results for "event" libraries on microjs: http://microjs.com/#event).

Your original question was how to use the built-in DOM API events, so find a simple (a bit naive) implementation that uses just standard DOM API below:

```js
// CustomEvent polyfill for IE9-11 from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent
(function () {
  if ( typeof window.CustomEvent === "function" ) return false;
  function CustomEvent ( event, params ) {
    params = params || { bubbles: false, cancelable: false, detail: undefined };
    var evt = document.createEvent( 'CustomEvent' );
    evt.initCustomEvent( event, params.bubbles, params.cancelable, params.detail );
    return evt;
   }
  CustomEvent.prototype = window.Event.prototype;
  window.CustomEvent = CustomEvent;
})();

var events = (function() {
  var eventRoot = document.createElement('div');
  function event(strOrObj, data) {
    return typeof strOrObj === 'string' ? new CustomEvent(strOrObj, data ? {detail: data} : undefined) : strOrObj
  };
  return {
    dispatch: function(evt, data) {
      eventRoot.dispatchEvent(event(evt, data));
    },
    addListener: function(evt, listener1, listener2, etc) {
      var listeners = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
      listeners.forEach(function(fn) {
        eventRoot.addEventListener(evt, fn);
      });
    },
    removeListener: function(evt, listener1, listener2, etc) {
      var listeners = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
      listeners.forEach(function(fn) {
        eventRoot.removeEventListener(evt, listener);
      });
    }
  };
}());

events.addListener('click', 
  function(e) { console.log(e.detail.data); },
  function(e) { console.log(e.type); }
)
events.dispatch('click', {data: 'test'})
```

You need a polyfill (included above) for CustomEvent for IE9-11. This solution will work for most cases, but devs tend to favor publish-subscribe patterns for non-DOMElement event dispatching/listening. You'll find a lot of easy to use libraries at http://microjs.com/#pubsub. Don't be fooled by how "old" some of these libraries are, they are simple and complete, and most work like a charm.

Comment: You don't need a DOM element for this, just need an object that either implements or inherits from `EventTarget`

Comment: My original question was how not to use the DOM at all. EventTarget is what I was looking for.

Comment: @PatrickEvans, it's [not supported on Safari or IE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/EventTarget), you will need a polyfill (maybe Babel does this automatically, I don't know).

Comment: @PaulaVega, EventTarget is part of the [DOM spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/EventTarget), you won't find it in other JS environments, only browser. As such your original question is still, how to use DOM events.